# Prove an inequality by Second partial derivative test?

Tags: inequality, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real positive numbers. 
Define a function $f$ on the domain $D = \{(x,~y) \in \Bbb R ^2 | x>0,~y>0 \}$ as follows:
$$
f(x,y)=ax^{a+b+c}+by^{a+b+c}+c-(a+b+c)x^ay^b.
$$

> Prove for $(x, y)\in D$ that
>   $$
> ax^{a+b+c}+by^{a+b+c}+c\geq (a+b+c)x^ay^b.
> $$

By [Second partial derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test) I found that $(1,1)$ is the unique critical point and especially the local minimum
of $f$. If $(1,1)$ is the global minimum then the inequality is proved. 
Are we available to prove that?

Added: Any local minimum of a convex function is also a global minimum.
I wonder if this fact is useful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just AM-GM:
$$\frac{a}{a+b+c}\cdot x^{a+b+c}+\frac{b}{a+b+c}\cdot y^{a+b+c}+\frac{c}{a+b+c}\cdot1\geq$$

$$\geq\left(x^{a+b+c}\right)^{\frac{a}{a+b+c}}\cdot\left(y^{a+b+c}\right)^{\frac{b}{a+b+c}}\cdot1^{\frac{c}{a+b+c}}=x^ay^b$$

Comment: I'm glad to know the AM-Gm works fine here. I was looking for whether or not exist a method as the title said.